# Ruby inspect vs to_s in Rspec

Tags: ruby, string, unit-testing, rspec

Consider the following test for `rspec`:

```
class RspecTest
  def initialize
  end

  def to_s
    "foo"
  end
end

describe RspecTest do
  it "should return foo (to_s)" do
    RspecTest.new.should == "foo"
  end

  it "should return foo (inspect)" do
    RspecTest.new.inspect == "foo"
  end
end
```

And when tested through `rspec`:

```
%: rspec rspec_test.rb 
F.

Failures:

  1) RspecTest should return foo (to_s)
     Failure/Error: RspecTest.new.should == "foo"
       expected: "foo"
            got: foo (using ==)
       Diff:
     # ./rspec_test.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00059 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

So the first test fails, whereas the second test passes. Why is that?

Comment: Another way it's add == operator to class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second test passes, because it doesn't test anything. It doesn't contain any expectation (i.e. a call to `should` or `should_not`). It *cannot* fail, because there is nothing *to* fail.

The first test fails, because you are asserting that an instance of `RspecTest` is equal to the string `'foo'`. This cannot possibly be true. How could those two objects possibly be equal if they aren't even the same *kind* of object?

Judging by the description of the test, you didn't actually mean to test whether the instance of `RspecTest` is equal to the string `'foo'`, but rather whether the return value of the instance method `to_s` is equal to the string `'foo'`. However, you never call `to_s` anywhere.

Let's first fix the two obvious problems. Now, we have a test like this:

```
it 'should return foo (to_s)' do
  RspecTest.new.to_s.should == 'foo'
end

it 'should return foo (inspect)' do
  RspecTest.new.inspect.should == 'foo'
end
```

There is some unnecessary duplication there with the two `RspecTest.new` calls, so let's fix that by simply making `RspecTest.new` the default subject:

```
  subject { RspecTest.new }

  it 'should return foo (to_s)' do
    subject.to_s.should == 'foo'
  end

  it 'should return foo (inspect)' do
    subject.inspect.should == 'foo'
  end
```

And actually, if you don't supply an explicit subject, then RSpec will walk up the chain of nested `describe` blocks until it finds a class, and will simply call that class's `new` method to provide the subject. So, we can just delete the `subject` declaration:

```
  it 'should return foo (to_s)' do
    subject.to_s.should == 'foo'
  end

  it 'should return foo (inspect)' do
    subject.inspect.should == 'foo'
  end
```

Personally, I prefer to let RSpec provide the example name by itself, so that the example name and the actual example code don't get out of sync, so I'd probably write that more like this:

```
describe RspecTest do
  describe '#to_s' do
    it { subject.to_s.should == 'foo' }
  end

  describe '#inspect' do
    it { subject.inspect.should == "foo" }
  end
end
```

Which yields:

```
RspecTest
  #to_s
    should == "foo"
  #inspect
    should == "foo"

Finished in 0.16023 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures
```

Last but not least, your initializer isn't actually doing anything, so you don't need it. All together, my version looks like this:

```
class RspecTest
  def to_s; 'foo' end
end

describe RspecTest do
  describe '#to_s' do
    it { subject.to_s.should == 'foo' }
  end

  describe '#inspect' do
    it { subject.inspect.should == "foo" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your test should be the following (and they'll both pass). The first one is missing the actual `to_s` call, and the seocnd one is missing the `.should`:

```
describe RspecTest do
  it "should return foo (to_s)" do
    RspecTest.new.to_s.should == "foo"
  end

  it "should return foo (inspect)" do
    RspecTest.new.inspect.should == "foo"
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree that adding `to_s` makes it pass. But why can't I just drop it? Shouldn't it automatically call `to_s`? And if not, what is it calling?

Comment: It's comparing a new instance of `RspecTest` to the string `foo`, which of course are not equal. Using `==` means object equality, which is performed by comparing both objects' memory addresses.

Comment: What's throwing you off is that it says `got: foo (using ==)`, however notice foo isn't in quotes. This just means that it expected a string, and got an object of type RspecTest instead. To see what I mean, get rid of your to_s method and your first test would then say something like `got: #<RspecTest:0x2ac14d0> (using ==)`.